# Cell Broadcast Reception Symbian Qt

Tags: qt, cell, symbian, broadcast

I am trying to develop a basic application with Symbian Qt framework that reads my cell broadcast messages. I have had little luck in finding Qt API's for this purpose. Are there any API's I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for Messaging API In Qt for Symbian http://www.developer.nokia.com/document/Mobile_Hands-on_Labs/Qt/MobilityMessaging/.

But According to me to Developing Broadcast messages application its better to follow Native code(Symbian C++).You Can find Symbian c++ Sample Examples in this link http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/SDK_API_Plug-in.